# How can I determine why a process is dying?

Tags: centos, ruby, sinatra

On a CentOS 6.5 server I am running a very simple HTTP listener with Sinatra that exists simply to accept POST requests and pass the payload content of the POST request to another service.

I often find that the process with the PID of the Sinatra service no longer exists, with no explanation in the logs.

I have debug-level logging in the Sinatra code and still have no clues towards what is happening on the box to cause the process to die.

What can I do on the Linux side of this problem to monitor this particular process and determine what is causing it be killed?

Comment: `/var/log/messages` is a good start

Comment: This question is being voted for closure because the author does not show a level of technical understanding or appropriate due diligence in researching the topic that the community judges as being a minimum barrier to participate.

Comment: `/var/log/messages` was my first stop in trying to solve this issue and there was nothing regarding the Sinatra service's particular PID.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to do

strace -p pid-number >& /tmp/process.txt

Once the process has died you can study the contents of /tmp/process.txt

pid-number should be replaced with the numeric pid if the process you want to study.